# Using Gson How to convert Json object that contains object of an interface that implemented by many classes - Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an object of `UserMsg` that I want to send using `JSON`

```
public class UserMsg {
private String Type; 
private UserData userData; 

//Getters & Setters }
```

`UserData` is an Interface

there are many classes implementing `UserData` .. and everytime I send the Json Object Its `userData` could be an object of any of these classes.

so on the Receiving side I used this code:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 
        UserMsg usermsg = gson.fromJson(JsonObject,UserMsg.class);
```

and got this error:

> Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface UserData. Register
>   an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

I tried to Register an `InstanceCreator` for `UserData` but It doesn't work so I need the right way to make it run.

Comment: So how do you know which class the JSON represents?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm casting the object userData according to the String object "Type"

Comment: But you don't have that until after the outer object has been reconstituted, using the normal Gson paradigm.

Comment: @HotLicks `gson.fromJson(JsonObject,UserMsg.class);` is throwing the exception I mentioned above

Comment: Yeah, because Gson is trying to create a UserData "object".  But of course there is no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a custom Adapter and inside the read/write methods you may set the parsing methodology in order to handle different classes implementing your `UserData` interface. Something like this:

```
public class UserMsgAdapter extends TypeAdapter {

  @Override
  public UserMsg read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    final UserMsg data = new UserMsg();

    in.beginObject();
    while (in.hasNext()) {

      in.nextName();
      if(in.nextString().equals(someType))
         // create one instance of a particular implementation

      }
    }
    in.endObject();

    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(final JsonWriter out, final UserMsg msg) throws IOException {
    out.beginObject();
    // write according to the instance type
    out.endObject();
  }
}
```

And dont forget to register this custom adapter:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(UserMsg.class, new UserMsgAdapter());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Comment: Is there any efficient way to get UserData object from JsonReader and then cast it to the right class.. because the object is a complex one not simple